# C# foreach string in array process in groups of X amout

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to iterate through an array and process every X amount (in this case 90), then move go back though the loop until the array has been exhausted. This could be achieved easily if the array was a fixed amount, sadly it is not.

```
//Test range of 90 for total tag collection
        private void TestExcelRange(string[] tagCollection)
        {
            string DellTag = null;
            int maxGroupAmmount = 90;
            foreach(string singleTag in tagCollection)
            {
                //process in groups of 90 -- maxGroupAmmount

                if (singleTag != "NONE")
                {
                    DellTag += singleTag+ "|";
                }
                //After 90 process again until tagCollection is complete               
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to process the string[] in chunks of 90 elements?  So if the array was size 100, then process 90 elements first and then process the last 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that splits a list or array into chunks of a certain size:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetChunks<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements, int size)
{
    var list = elements.ToList();
    while (list.Count > 0)
    {
        var chunk = list.Take(size);
        yield return chunk;

        list = list.Skip(size).ToList();
    }
}
```

You can then process your array like this:

```
private void TestExcelRange(string[] tagCollection)
{
    string DellTag = null;
    int maxGroupAmount = 90;
    var chunks = GetChunks(tagCollection, maxGroupAmount);

    foreach (IEnumerable<string> chunk in chunks)
    {
        //process in groups of 90      
    }            
}
```

Comment: This will work, but instead of creating so many nearly-full-length lists, why not use `ToArray` and then `Array.CopyTo` and avoid all the extra copying?  Or do a fully-lazy implementation.